# How do I get a list of JNI libraries which are loaded?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Just what the subject says, is there a way in Java to get a list of all the JNI native libraries which have been loaded at any given time?

Answer (score 35):

[**DISCLAIMER**: Note that this solution always was hackish. And in most cases won't work anymore nowadays. Check [Benjamins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007861/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-jni-libraries-which-are-loaded/55392604#55392604) for more info]

---

There is a way to determine all currently loaded native libraries if you meant that. Already unloaded libraries can't be determined.

Based on the work of Svetlin Nakov ([Extract classes loaded in JVM to single JAR](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/08/27/extract-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm-into-a-single-jar/)) I did a POC which gives you the names of the loaded native libraries from the application classloader and the classloader of the current class.

First the simplified version with no bu....it exception handling, nice error messages, javadoc, ....

Get the private field in which the class loader stores the already loaded libraries via reflection

```
public class ClassScope {
    private static final java.lang.reflect.Field LIBRARIES;
    static {
        LIBRARIES = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames");
        LIBRARIES.setAccessible(true);
    }
    public static String[] getLoadedLibraries(final ClassLoader loader) {
        final Vector<String> libraries = (Vector<String>) LIBRARIES.get(loader);
        return libraries.toArray(new String[] {});
    }
}
```

Call the above like this

```
final String[] libraries = ClassScope.getLoadedClasses(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); //MyClassName.class.getClassLoader()
```

And voilá *`libraries`* holds the names of the loaded native libraries.

Get the full source code [here](http://pastebin.com/aDgGqjEr) and [here](http://pastebin.com/eVXFdgr9)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and got this error message: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class net.grow.web.ClassScope can not access a member of class java.lang.ClassLoader with modifiers "private static"

Comment: Try adding LIBRARIES.setAccessible(true); after the call to getDeclaredField if you don't have that already. If it still fails then either your JVM is not SUN compatible or there is a SecurityManager in place which prevents you from using the reflection mechanism

Comment: A last idea (if applicable to your environment) would be to write your own ClassLoader as an Object Adapter for the normal ClassLoader.  And there implement some kind of "logging" for the calls to load and loadLibrary

Comment: Would anybody be so kind as to re-host the code from the download site onto PasteBin or some other ad-free download system? I'm not actually able to access that download site at work.

Comment: Here you go: [AllLoadedNativeLibrariesInJVM.java](http://pastebin.com/aDgGqjEr) and [ClassScope.java](http://pastebin.com/eVXFdgr9)

Comment: I am using Android Studio and I get a "java.lang.RuntimeException: ClassScope::getLoadedLibraries() cannot be used in this JRE". Any idea about this?

Comment: +1 - Note that in recent version of Java, at least, `loadedLibraryNames` is a static member, so the `loader` arg to `LIBRARIES.get(loader)` is ignored.

Comment: `No field loadedLibraryNames in class Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;`

Answer (score 12):

I've built on top of [jitter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007861/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-jni-libraries-which-are-loaded/1008631#1008631). This allows you to find out who (ClassLoader, Class) loaded each native library.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Helper functions for native libraries.
 * <p/>
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public class NativeLibraries
{
    private final Field loadedLibraryNames;
    private final Field systemNativeLibraries;
    private final Field nativeLibraries;
    private final Field nativeLibraryFromClass;
    private final Field nativeLibraryName;

    /**
     * Creates a new NativeLibraries.
     * <p/>
     * @throws NoSuchFieldException if one of ClassLoader's fields cannot be found
     */
    public NativeLibraries() throws NoSuchFieldException
    {
        this.loadedLibraryNames = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames");
        loadedLibraryNames.setAccessible(true);

        this.systemNativeLibraries = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("systemNativeLibraries");
        systemNativeLibraries.setAccessible(true);

        this.nativeLibraries = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("nativeLibraries");
        nativeLibraries.setAccessible(true);

        Class<?> nativeLibrary = null;
        for (Class<?> nested : ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredClasses())
        {
            if (nested.getSimpleName().equals("NativeLibrary"))
            {
                nativeLibrary = nested;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.nativeLibraryFromClass = nativeLibrary.getDeclaredField("fromClass");
        nativeLibraryFromClass.setAccessible(true);

        this.nativeLibraryName = nativeLibrary.getDeclaredField("name");
        nativeLibraryName.setAccessible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the names of native libraries loaded across all class loaders.
     * <p/>
     * @return a list of native libraries loaded
     */
    public List<String> getLoadedLibraries()
    {
        try
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
            final Vector<String> result = (Vector<String>) loadedLibraryNames.get(null);
            return result;
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the native libraries loaded by the system class loader.
     * <p/>
     * @return a Map from the names of native libraries to the classes that loaded them
     */
    public Map<String, Class<?>> getSystemNativeLibraries()
    {
        try
        {
            Map<String, Class<?>> result = new HashMap<>();
            @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
            final Vector<Object> libraries = (Vector<Object>) systemNativeLibraries.get(null);
            for (Object nativeLibrary : libraries)
            {
                String libraryName = (String) nativeLibraryName.get(nativeLibrary);
                Class<?> fromClass = (Class<?>) nativeLibraryFromClass.get(nativeLibrary);
                result.put(libraryName, fromClass);
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Map from the names of native libraries to the classes that loaded them.
     * <p/>
     * @param loader the ClassLoader that loaded the libraries
     * @return an empty Map if no native libraries were loaded
     */
    public Map<String, Class<?>> getNativeLibraries(final ClassLoader loader)
    {
        try
        {
            Map<String, Class<?>> result = new HashMap<>();
            @SuppressWarnings("UseOfObsoleteCollectionType")
            final Vector<Object> libraries = (Vector<Object>) nativeLibraries.get(loader);
            for (Object nativeLibrary : libraries)
            {
                String libraryName = (String) nativeLibraryName.get(nativeLibrary);
                Class<?> fromClass = (Class<?>) nativeLibraryFromClass.get(nativeLibrary);
                result.put(libraryName, fromClass);
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * The same as {@link #getNativeLibraries()} except that all ancestor classloaders are processed
     * as well.
     * <p/>
     * @param loader the ClassLoader that loaded (or whose ancestors loaded) the libraries
     * @return an empty Map if no native libraries were loaded
     */
    public Map<String, Class<?>> getTransitiveNativeLibraries(final ClassLoader loader)
    {
        Map<String, Class<?>> result = new HashMap<>();
        ClassLoader parent = loader.getParent();
        while (parent != null)
        {
            result.putAll(getTransitiveNativeLibraries(parent));
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        result.putAll(getNativeLibraries(loader));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a map of library names to the classes that loaded them to a map of library names to
     * the classloaders that loaded them.
     * <p/>
     * @param libraryToClass a map of library names to the classes that loaded them
     * @return a map of library names to the classloaders that loaded them
     */
    public Map<String, ClassLoader> getLibraryClassLoaders(Map<String, Class<?>> libraryToClass)
    {
        Map<String, ClassLoader> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : libraryToClass.entrySet())
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getClassLoader());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list containing the classloader and its ancestors.
     * <p/>
     * @param loader the classloader
     * @return a list containing the classloader, its parent, and so on
     */
    public static List<ClassLoader> getTransitiveClassLoaders(ClassLoader loader)
    {
        List<ClassLoader> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ClassLoader parent = loader.getParent();
        result.add(loader);
        while (parent != null)
        {
            result.add(parent);
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example how to use this class? `new NativeLibraries()` fails with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: loadedLibraryNames`

Comment: @EricDuminil see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55392604/14731

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here's [jitter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007861/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-jni-libraries-which-are-loaded/1008631#1008631) again, this time as a small Scala method:

```scala
def loadedLibs: Seq[String] = {
  val libs = classOf[ClassLoader].getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames")
  libs.setAccessible(true)
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  libs.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
    .asInstanceOf[java.util.Vector[String]]
    .asScala
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Nicolas mentioned Scala, here is one way to do jitter's solution via JRuby (tested in 1.6 and 1.7):

```
require 'java'
import 'java.lang.ClassLoader'
f = ClassLoader.java_class.declared_field('loadedLibraryNames')
f.accessible = true
f.value(ClassLoader.system_class_loader).to_array.to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

In Clojure, copy/pastable at the REPL:

```
(-> (doto (.getDeclaredField ClassLoader "loadedLibraryNames")
      (.setAccessible true))
    (.get (ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy (tested in 2.3.3):

```
libs = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames")
libs.setAccessible(true)
libraries = libs.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
```

Comment: For those who avoid this answer because of the Groovy at the top, it works in java just fine, you just have to wrap it all in a try block and catch some exceptions. The libs.get get returns a Set<String> with all the dlls loaded at the time (I assume by the given class loader)

Answer (score 0):

as of Janurary 2019, the correct answer (from jdk9+ ondwards) is: There is no way anymore to get the List of loaded libraries.

Although the mentioned field (`loadedLibraryNames`) still exists in `hotspot`-type VMs, it does not exist in others (like `openj9`). Also, if you try this on jdk9 onwards, you will get a warning on your terminal, that this access will be revoked in Java 12 onwards:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by <class> (file:<file>) to method|constructor
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of <file>
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

That said,
* this method only works on a very specific JVM. do not rely on this, as someone may use another mature VM like `openj9`, `azul`, `corretto`, etc.
* It won't work since Java 9 officially, but will crash your JVM (or yield unexpected output) starting from Java 12.

Comment: You will be able to fix the warning with an `--add-opens` argument to your VM, so that part's not a big deal. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230678/733092 How do you know that field is being removed? I tried Googling it.