# How to unload Dll in java?

Tags: java, dll

I have written a Java agent in Lotus Notes 8.5 to reset token's PIN using
 IAIKPKCS11wrapper. When the agent is loaded for the first time it worked
 fine. But after I close and restart the agent then it failed. Checking the
 console output I discovered the following error:

Exception in thread "AgentThread: JavaAgent"
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pkcs11wrapper (Library is already loaded in
 another ClassLoader)

I have searched the group but the closest I could find is that it is not
 possible to unload the DLL library but I still have no idea how to handle
 it.

Can anyone point me the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139386/check-if-a-dll-library-is-already-loaded-java

Comment: To unload a DLL, you need to unload the ClassLoader which loaded it. OSGI can handle this ugliness for you, but you can create a ClassLoader to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the related SO questions, found [this tutorial](http://codethesis.com/tutorial.php?id=1) on DLL unloading.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the jar to your Lotus Notes classpath in `notes.ini`:

```
JavaUserClasses=...;yourAgent.jar
```

or copy your jar to the default Notes lib directory, which should be something like: `C:\lotus\notes\jvm\lib\ext`

Another thing to try is to put your dll in `C:\lotus\notes.`