# Custom class loader for loading dll in applet

Tags: java, dll, applet, classloader

To address the .dll file [loading/unloading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956145/how-to-unload-dll-in-java) with applets. I am loading, following [this tutorial](http://codethesis.com/sites/default/index.php?servlet=4&content=2), .dll files using a custom class loader as :

**1- Class Loader** (Copied from [tutorial](http://codethesis.com/sites/default/index.php?servlet=4&content=1))

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private static final String CLASS_NAME = CustomClassLoader.class.getName();

    private Map<String, Class<?>> classes;

    public CustomClassLoader() {
        super(CustomClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
        classes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return CustomClassLoader.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (classes.containsKey(name)) {
            return classes.get(name);
        }

        String path = name.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class";
        byte[] b = null;

        try {
            b = loadClassData(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class not found at path: " + new File(name).getAbsolutePath(), e); **
        }

        Class<?> c = defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
        resolveClass(c);
        classes.put(name, c);

        return c;
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String name) throws IOException {
        String methodName = CLASS_NAME + ".loadClassData";
        byte buff[] = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(name);
            int size = (int) file.length();
            buff = new byte[size];
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));
            in.readFully(buff);
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return buff;
    }
}
```

**2- A class to load .dll files**

```
public class DllLoader {

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = AppletReload.class.getName();

    static String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    private static String dllPath = javaHome + Constant.SMARTCARD_JACSPCSC_DLL_NAME;
    private static String dllPath1 = javaHome + Constant.SMARTCARD_RXTXSERIAL_DLL_NAME;

    public DllLoader() {
    }

    static {
        try {
            System.load(dllPath);
            Logger.write(LoggerConstant.TRACE, "JACSPCSC Dll loaded from the path: " + dllPath, "Dll Loader");
            System.load(dllPath1);
            Logger.write(LoggerConstant.TRACE, "RXTXSERIAL Dll loaded from the path: " + dllPath1, "Dll Loader");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log exception;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using this class loader:

```
cl = new CustomClassLoader();
ca = cl.findClass("com.DllLoader");
a = ca.newInstance();
```

The motivation behind loading .dll using custom class loader is that it would guarantee the unloading as well and this is what most of the answers to question on .dll loading/unloading suggest. But in my case, `loadClassData()` (a function in my classLoader) thows this exception:

```
   loadClassData,Error: com\DllLoader.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: com\DllLoader.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

and the absolute path of file is show logged as:

**C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\com.DllLoader

I think this is where its searching for the file, and .jar file of applet isn't located here.

I would appreciate if anyone can point out mistake I am making or tell how can I guide browser to look for class file in correct folder.

P.S: Kindly note that a answer to seemingly [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872905/applet-class-loader-cannot-find-a-class-in-the-applets-jar) don't solve this problem.

Comment: *"To address the .dll file loading/unloading issue with applets."* You were getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` as mentioned in that thread?  BTW - If the applet were launched free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), it would almost certainly fix that error.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Yes you are right, i was getting "UnsatisfiedLinkError" previously, while reloading the applet in the same browser instance.

Comment: Well, like I said, a solution is likely to be found if *"..the applet were launched free floating using Java Web Start.."*.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Do you mean custom class loading won't work this way?

Comment: Before I even consider answering that, tell me why you do not launch the applet using JWS.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I don't know much about JWS but i read Its a bit different than applets and takes effort to install. My application is in use for an year, by non-technical users mainly and i am afraid that client might resist idea. Plus applet interacts with browser using javascript. Please, correct me if I am wrong or lacking concepts and kindly point me to some appropriate links. Thanks

Comment: *"Plus applet interacts with browser using javascript."*  The rest of your points were way off, but that is a killer for JWS.  Why does the page use JavaScript (what for)?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: This applet after downloading communicates with a backend process. It uses javascript for mainly to pass request attributes/parameter to applet like  logged in user information also includes user specific translations for gui, address and port of server ip and port of backend process and some other applet specific paramter( mainly configurable things).

Comment: OK  I think JWS is back in the picture.  A JWS app. can communicate with anything on the server that an applet can.  As for the 'configurable things', do you mean applet `param` elements?  To answer your question - I don't know for sure, but I doubt it.  The problem is that you have less control over when natives are loaded or unloaded when an applet is deployed in a browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4221/discussion-between-andrew-thompson-and-umer-hayat)

Comment: ..Which reminds me.  What happened with the deployment?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Actually, we have to stick with the applet due to many reasons (mostly non-technical) so, as a workaround we now ship new jar with different dlls (actually same dlls with different names), which is not very nice but its working fine.It will take time to convince team and (especially) client to considered JWS. Which we think would be THE solution. But thanks for this discussion, this was very helpful in providing a lead to initiate a discussion on JWS with my Team ;)