# Detect Dlls in Java

Tags: java, dll

How can I tell if a dll is loaded in java?

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific than that.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139386/check-if-a-dll-library-is-already-loaded-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check if a dll library is already loaded? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139386/check-if-a-dll-library-is-already-loaded-java)