# JDK9: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred. org.python.core.PySystemState

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I'm trying to run DMelt programs (http://jwork.org/dmelt/) program using Java9 (JDK9), and it gives me errors such as:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.python.core.PySystemState (file:/dmelt/jehep/lib/jython/jython.jar) to method java.io.Console.encoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.PySystemState
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

How can I fix it? I was trying to add –illegal-access=permit to the last line of the script "dmelt.sh" (I'm using bash in Linux), but this did not solve this problem. I'm very frustrating with this. I was using this program very often, for very long time. Maybe I should never move to JDK9

Answer (score 46):

The *ideal* way to resolve this would be to

> **reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.PySystemState**

and asking them to fix such reflective access going forward.

---

> If the default mode permits illegal reflective access, however, then
> it's essential to make that known so that people aren't surprised when
> this is no longer the default mode in a future release.

From one of the [threads on the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2017-May/012673.html) :

```
--illegal-access=permit
```

> This will be the **default** mode for JDK 9.  It opens every package in
> every explicit module to code in all unnamed modules, i.e., code on
> the class path, just as `--permit-illegal-access` does today.

> The first illegal reflective-access operation causes a warning to be
> issued, as with `--permit-illegal-access`, but no warnings are issued
> after that point. This single warning will describe how to enable
> further warnings.

```
--illegal-access=deny
```

> This disables all illegal reflective-access operations except for
> those enabled by other command-line options, such as `--add-opens`.
> This **will become the default** mode in a future release.

Warning messages in any mode can be avoided, as before, by the judicious use of the `--add-exports` and `--add-opens` options.

---

Hence a current temporary solution available is to use `--add-exports` as the VM arguments as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) :

```
--add-exports module/package=target-module(,target-module)*
```

> Updates module to **`export`** package to `target-module`, regardless of
> module declaration. The `target-module` can be all *unnamed* to export to
> all unnamed modules.

This would allow the `target-module` to access all public types in `package`. In case you want to access the JDK internal classes which would still be encapsulated, you would have to allow a *deep reflection* using the `--add-opens` argument as:

```
--add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*
```

> Updates module to **`open`** package to `target-module`, regardless of module
> declaration.

In your case to currently accessing the `java.io.Console`, you can simply add this as a VM option -

```
--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

---

Also, note from the same thread as linked above

*When `deny` becomes the default mode then I expect `permit` to remain supported for at least one release so that developers can continue to migrate their code.  The `permit`, `warn`, and `debug` modes will, over time, be removed, as will the `--illegal-access` option itself.*

So it's better to change the implementation and follow the ideal solution to it.

Answer (score 6):

DMelt seems to use Jython and this warning is something that the Jython maintainers will need to address. There is an issue tracking it here:
http://bugs.jython.org/issue2582

Comment: It looks like Jython 2,7 developers are clueless too. Their last report was in April 2017. They have not solved this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Real issue is a problem in the JDK. There is actually no illegal access, but the JDK method trySetAccessible is misbehaving. This will hopefully be fixed in a future JDK version.

try solve below answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454995/how-to-hide-warning-illegal-reflective-access-in-java-9-without-jvm-argument)

Comment: "Real issue is the problem with JDK" just by that I looked into my JDK setup in build path. Helped me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this error, you need to redefine `maven-war-plugin` to a newer one. For example:

```xml
<plugins>
    . . .
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

---

<sup>Works for `jdk-12`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Jython developers do not have any practical solution for jdk9, according to this post http://bugs.jython.org/issue2582.
The previous explanation seems very long to figure out what should done. I just want jdk9 behaves exactly as jdk1.4 - 1.8, i.e be totally silent. The JVM strength in backward comparability. I'm totally OK to have additional options in JDK9, but new features cannot break applications

Comment: This issue needs changes in the Jython code that is hacking into the private encoding method in java.io.Console. The warning serves as a reminder that the hack will break once access to JDK internals is blocked. You can of course workaround it by opening the java.io package for deep reflection (`--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`) but better if Jython addressed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Java update 9, the "illegal reflective access operation has occurred" warning occurs.

To remove the warning message. You can replace maven-compiler-plugin with maven-war-plugin and/or updating the maven-war-plugin with the latest version in your pom.xml.  Following are 2 examples:

Change version from:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    ...
       
    ...
</plugin>
```

To:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    ...
     ...
</plugin>
```

Change the artifactId and version From:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

TO:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>prepare-war</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exploded</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When i re-run Maven Build or Maven Install, the "illegal reflective access operation has occurred" is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the fix below works for java 9 as well:

In my case the java open jdk version was 10.0.2 and got the same error (An illegal reflective access opeeration has occurred). I upgraded maven to version 3.6.0 on linux, and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Came here while working on a Kotlin Spring project. Resolved the issue by:

```
cd /project/root/
touch .mvn/jvm.config
echo "--illegal-access=permit" >> .mvn/jvm.config
```

Answer (score 0):

Some recent feedback.

as stated in the java error code

```
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

This future release is JDK 17, where the launcher parameter `--illegal-access` will stop working.

More information direct from Oracle can be found here: [JEP 403 link 1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403) and [JEP 403 link 2](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8263547)

> With this change, **it will no longer be possible for end users to use
> the --illegal-access option** to enable access to internal elements of
> the JDK. (A list of the packages affected is available here.) The
> sun.misc and sun.reflect packages will still be exported by the
> jdk.unsupported module, and will still be open so that code can access
> their non-public elements via reflection. No other JDK packages will
> be open in this way.
>
> **It will still be possible to use the --add-opens**
> command-line option, or the Add-Opens
> JAR-file manifest attribute, to open specific packages.

So the solution `--add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*` and the example `--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` will keep working for JDK 17 and future releases but the `--illegal-access` will not.