# Set JVM option for avoid error Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-9, cglib

I use Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1, JDK 9.0.4, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 Ultimate, Gradle 4.5.1 . Spring Boot RC1 version (strictly, Spring Framework 5.0.3.RELEASE) has a known issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15859 , I also see it at here https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-java-9#create-a-spring-boot-application

Spring developer suggest that

> You can switch this off by adding -illegal-access=deny to the command
>   line (the default in Java 9 is permit).

I choose menu **Help \ Edit Custom VM Options...**, then add new options at the last line of file.

[image]

Then I catch error

```
> Unrecognized option: -illegal-access=deny 
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. 
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Full console log

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=50382 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50383:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/donhuvy/Documents/source_code/gitlab.com/Donhu/accounting_vy/source_code/out/production/classes:/Users/donhuvy/Documents/source_code/gitlab.com/Donhu/accounting_vy/source_code/out/production/resources:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/2.0.0.RC1/84315afdba22f18e8473dabe39507c2f7329bbf/spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/2.0.0.RC1/5cd08bbbfaa424ab2e250e51dd9d13bd38a1d42d/spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.13.Final/cdef4ec0e1c9739942fbd16bb6b355d5fb804fba/hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.13.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.13.Final/830492a74b3013ef75135ea4120b2ac23fa7ad9f/hibernate-core-5.2.13.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/99f802e0cb3e953ba3d6e698795c4aeb98d37c48/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/d044c784e41d026778693fb44a8026c1fd9a7506/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/3a3c6a62719d967175b76b63925f1fb495f11437/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.2.Final/52afb5762c704a6b586e27742470c08f91877fc1/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.1/ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.0.0.RC1/63ff3ff19491dc47d0b9b47e7770ddd1dbeeacb0/spring-boot-starter-validation-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.0-rc.8/micrometer-core-1.0.0-rc.8.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-spring4/2.26/e5f2654b343c31078d9b5c8a4f43b838b320099f/jersey-spring4-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.26/8723d05d1fe2fdda54d0921836ea5daa5abe5f00/jersey-container-servlet-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.26/66a0d51facf1e49e2353ff0d2a2d4a9e2fa3f836/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-bean-validation/2.26/33747b4e8a07c53550ee1cbe7fc4321600842c5a/jersey-bean-validation-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.26/aa8eff3d591641dadd7c9880bb73b59bf46d4c82/jersey-server-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.26/ce3109479991527107921ca5e7943a6e7e20db80/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context-support/5.0.3.RELEASE/853800b9fe479931f8ec5aaf7c19e285d5de1402/spring-context-support-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/spring-bridge/2.5.0-b42/7cedc63a9079e87b5a2685c054e61cfce8c44837/spring-bridge-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-context-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.6.0/a055c648842c4954c1f7db7254f45d9ad565e278/javax.mail-1.6.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.9.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/3.0.1.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.7.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2/2.26/df27f7d7577acf4b532684448021632098924dab/jersey-hk2-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/config-types/2.5.0-b42/3e927a0624955d10bec3eb5424a1e6ca3d5f92ae/config-types-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-config/2.5.0-b42/de522871d987e2bf502753c807461f9ee805f6bd/hk2-config-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-core/2.5.0-b42/7a4954663f1b65b1938fd275b34bbf1e23965381/hk2-core-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-runlevel/2.5.0-b42/6502d8997ac961f0d2d16d90e838d25626c1a37b/hk2-runlevel-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.5.0-b42/9d6edc0cb226401a8316e67d81bfc37cb626ef91/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.22.0-CR2/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.7.9/byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.8.13/bfc5a877fd80648e5467239d370735654aaf7a92/aspectjrt-1.8.13.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/2.7.6/HikariCP-2.7.6.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.0.RC1/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.0.RC1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.10.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.26/125b8d1040d121a5dc4ce6858e21a6160bed7afa/jersey-client-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb/2.26/791397ceb5d1c8f389664b1de3e4208c2ac1015b/jersey-media-jaxb-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.26/d96475745c5e72cafcbc4dc9e2e725f4d9683f21/jersey-common-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api/2.5.0-b42/7fd4e3d0f2cb37c80ad0dedee3f5ee69503eaf52/hk2-api-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-utils/2.5.0-b42/102a344e1728825e865a8986d7605602aba3c3b6/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/snakeyaml-1.19.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.2/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.9.2/8abd01f740ef04d05811bbca5612371bf034b05e/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.2/jackson-databind-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.10/HdrHistogram-2.1.10.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.13/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-entity-filtering/2.26/a8ea15c9cd0bd8b090dbbf0f0e43aa39604f3433/jersey-entity-filtering-2.26.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1/426a0862406536e690c7caa8bb6ed32191986fac/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.2/jackson-core-2.9.2.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/osgi-resource-locator/1.0.1/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/class-model/2.5.0-b42/a9824e8ed9748f3622394d6d32098cc1bb2a0ea1/class-model-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.4.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.5.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2.external/aopalliance-repackaged/2.5.0-b42/e74beab6ca12e9e745eb47ca61729d9452b96f0c/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2.external/asm-all-repackaged/2.5.0-b42/3afd5d4f63116e8c00b430f32092282e5e475ce8/asm-all-repackaged-2.5.0-b42.jar com.donhuvy.AccountingVyApplication
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/d044c784e41d026778693fb44a8026c1fd9a7506/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/2.3.0/d044c784e41d026778693fb44a8026c1fd9a7506/jaxb-api.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/3a3c6a62719d967175b76b63925f1fb495f11437/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.0/3a3c6a62719d967175b76b63925f1fb495f11437/jaxb-core.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-2.5.0-b42.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-utils.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/javax.annotation-api.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/javax.inject.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-api.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/aopalliance-repackaged.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/config-types.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-core.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-config.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/tiger-types.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hibernate-validator.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/validation-api.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/jboss-logging.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/classmate.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-locator.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/javax.inject.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/javassist.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/hk2-runlevel.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/class-model.jar,file:/Users/donhuvy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2/2.5.0-b42/adc396d57e9cada50f57d32cdabaf31a20a758d/asm-all-repackaged.jar
08:34:57.775 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
08:34:57.778 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/]
08:34:57.778 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/Users/donhuvy/Documents/source_code/gitlab.com/Donhu/accounting_vy/source_code/out/production/classes/, file:/Users/donhuvy/Documents/source_code/gitlab.com/Donhu/accounting_vy/source_code/out/production/resources/]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/donhuvy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

[image]

How to add option `-illegal-access=deny` to IntelliJ IDEA correctly?

update: Solution

[image]

Comment: 1) it is `--illegal-access=deny` (note the two dashes), 2) you should use value `permit`, not `deny` (deny disallows it entirely), and 3) you should set it on the run configuration of your application, not in the run configuration of IntelliJ itself. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys

Comment: I also try `--illegal-access=` but the same error happen. I also try `--illegal-access=permit` with 2 configuration files (`idea.vmoptions`, `idea.properites`), but still error.

Comment: About (3), Do you mean try configuration with `idea.vmoptions` also `idea.properties`?

Comment: No, you need to set in the run configuration of whatever it is you're running.

Comment: See my updated answer below. And considering deleting stale comments...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel specifying `--illegal-access=permit` makes no sense—that’s already the default.

Comment: @Holger Setting it to deny also doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, setting it to “deny” truly makes the warning disappear, as all these reflective accesses will entirely get rejected. All other available options only control the degree of warnings, but there is no option to permit the access without any warning…

Comment: code can be made to run on JDK 16 by specifying --illegal-access=permit according to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16-relnotes.html

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**:

To run your code you will need to add the option

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

to the JVM running your code as I noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671472/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-springframework-cglib-core-reflectutils1?noredirect=1&lq=1). When running your application in IntelliJ, the application VM options are set in the [Run/Debug Configuration VM options tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html), something like:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED    
-server
```

I don't use IntelliJ so this isn't tested.

---

I think you're combining your question with a partial and incorrect answer. I think you mean to ask the following question:

> When I run my JDK 9.0.4 Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 application in IntelliJ
>   IDEA 2017.3.4 Ultimate on my Mac using Gradle 4.5.1 as my build tool,
>   my application prints the following in the console:
>
> ```
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1() to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
> ```
>
> How can I get rid of this warning from the IntelliJ console?

**Is this what you're asking?** If so, replace your question with this text. And avoid using images when text can convey the content.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: This is screenshot: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/36272175-5735a992-12b3-11e8-8fa4-860e9820d2ff.png

Comment: My project use Gradle build tool, I create file `gradle.properties`, then put JVM option to it, but web app doesn't work. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html