# Cant build a jar with gradle and jdk 11

Tags: java, testing, gradle

When I try to create a jar build using gradle and jdk 11, the following error always occurs:

```
10:53:41: Executing task 'build'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar SKIPPED
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test FAILED
> Task :jacocoTestReport UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> failed to read class file /home/rodrigo/Projetos/Gaia/apipessoas/build/classes/java/test/com/rjdesenvolvimento/apipessoas/ApipessoasApplicationTests.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
Unsupported class file major version 55
10:54:50: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

I'm lost and need help. I have tried to change the mavencentral () repository to jcenter and without success.

When I use jdk 1.8 the error does not occur, however I need jdk 11, boss orders = (

ADD NEW INFO**************************

13:29:00: Executing task 'build'...

Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE

Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE

Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

Task :bootJar UP-TO-DATE

Task :jar

Task :assemble

Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE

Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE

Task :test

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/rodrigo/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.9.RELEASE/9f9a828936d81afd49a603bda9cc1aed863a0d85/spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

com.rjdesenvolvimento.apipessoas.ApipessoasApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED

java.lang.IllegalStateException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

1 test completed, 1 failed

Task :test FAILED
Task :jacocoTestReport

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/rodrigo/Projetos/Gaia/apipessoas/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 10s
7 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 4 up-to-date
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/rodrigo/Projetos/Gaia/apipessoas/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
13:29:11: Task execution finished 'build'.

Comment: Well, `Task :jar SKIPPED` - try to force-enable it and fix your test class ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Show new errors now. I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 6):

Which version of the Gradle are you using? By looking at your log, I can guess it's `4.8.1`. According to the [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5120), they fixed Gradle to make it work with Java 11 in `4.10.2` version, so all you should do, is to bump Gradle to this version or later version. If you are using Gradle wrapper, you can just edit `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file in your project and then update `distributionUrl` to the following one:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Probably, you can also do it in the following way in your project directory:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.10.2
```

and it should update or create your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

Once it's done, you can call the wrapper:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Show new errors now. I added more details to the question.

Comment: It seems like you need to upgrade Spring version to `5.1` or higher or add additional parameters to your build to fix this. Right now you have Spring `5.0.9`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671473/1150795

Comment: The warning gone. But the error with contextloads remains.

Comment: Have a look at the log. It says: `com.rjdesenvolvimento.apipessoas.ApipessoasApplicationTests > contextLoads FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. It's a failing test in your project. I don't know what's wrong there because I haven't seen the source code. I suppose you have to add a dependency to some bean. I don't know if it's integration or unit test. In the unit test, this dependency can be mocked - e.g. with Mockito.