# Spring boot multi module project with java 11 throws cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

I am creating a java 11 spring boot (2.1.3 version) multi module project  but I am getting a following exception while running the child module. Everything was working fine when I was running it as a single project ( no multi module).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: f

etch.App
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:413) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.1.3.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at legalAppFetchModule/fetch.App.main(App.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.1.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class fetch.App$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4423c935 (in module legalAppFetchModule) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x50378a4) because module legalAppFetchModule does not read unnamed module @0x50378a4
    at legalAppFetchModule/fetch.App$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4423c935.CGLIB$STATICHOOK1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at legalAppFetchModule/fetch.App$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4423c935.<clinit>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Please see the parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!--  lookup parent from repository --> 
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoMultiModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoMultiModule</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <modules>
        <module>fetch</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Please see the child pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoMultiModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
    <artifactId>fetch</artifactId>

  <name>fetch</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I could see a related spring issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20414) and so question  ([Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671472/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-springframework-cglib-core-reflectutils1)). According to them it must have fixed in spring5.1+ and I am using Spring-web.5.1.5. Therefore it should not have any issue.

For sake of completeness, please see my module path and module-info.java file of child module
[image]

module-info.java

```
open module legalAppFetchModule {
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.web;
}
```

Can somebody please throw some light

Comment: I have the same issue with Spring AOP on Spring data repositories. Spring Boot 2.1.4 and Java11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spring.core and spring.beans to your module dependencies (which you have already done).

Also, add this to the VM arguments of the arguments tab of the run configuration of your application:

```
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

You could also set this as a default option under *Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs* 
Select your JRE/JDK and edit. Add the option above under *Default VM Arguments*

Comment: adding --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
 worked. I went further and added just the instrument module which contained the java.lang.instrument classes. So basically I  only added --add-modules=java.instrument. in the vm args

Comment: I got the module info by running following command .                                             java --describe-module java.instrument
java.instrument@11.0.2
exports java.lang.instrument
requires java.base mandated
qualified exports sun.instrument to java.base

Comment: Do you know why this was not an issue with non-multi module  java 11 spring boot projects

Comment: Sadly, I don't know. I am new to the module system and found the solution through trial and error. As your solution with spring.beans helped me I wanted to return the favor and make sure others don't get stuck either.

Answer (score 0):

After adding spring-core and spring-beans to the module path , it does not complains any more still the server is not running fully but I think it may be due to something else which I have to look further. But as far the posted issue is concerned, it is solved

[image]

Comment: Now it fails with Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~....

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is related with incorrect modules configuration in your `package-info.java` file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class fetch.App$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4423c935 (in module legalAppFetchModule) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x50378a4) because module legalAppFetchModule does not read unnamed module @0x50378a4
```

In module `legalAppFetchModule`, please add in `module-info.java`:

```
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
```

If you are using Hibernate than probably you need also add to above command:

```
requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
```