# Spring boot - An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: spring-boot

I added new two dependencies to my demo application which are spring integration and spring integration file. After that I get the following warning in my console. Application works fine but it bothers me.

How can I overcome this issue?

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/TECH%20WORLD/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.7/spring-core-5.3.7.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class)
```

[image]

My project's SDK is version 15.0.2

**Spring boot version**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**Added dependencies**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-file -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: which JAVA version and which dependencies you added?

Comment: @dassum I've modified my main question with version details. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671472/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-springframework-cglib-core-reflectutils1 does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered by the following question!
[Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671472/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-springframework-cglib-core-reflectutils1)

It is noted that this is a a known Spring bug.

According to the findings this happens because when the new JDK 9 module system detected an illegal access that will be maybe disallowed in the future.

There are further readings...
[Java Platform, Standard Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7744EF96-5899-4FB2-B34E-86D49B2E89B6)