# Illegal reflective access by ReflectionUtils to method java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I changed the spring boot version from 2.4.6 to 2.6.3.

When I try to run `gradlew bootRun` I get the following error:

```
Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/abc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.15/e813c2311465672d3089fc7be8dbbadb04e64d6b/spring-core-5.3.15.jar) to method java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.decorateTask(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture)
```

Additional configurations:

- Spring Framework 5.3.6
- Spring Cloud 2020.0.2
- Java 11
- Gradle

I am not using `devtools` dependencies.

I have no clue of the error, I really appreciate if somebody can give me a solution of this error.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried also: --illegal-access=deny but I received the same error

Comment: Deny will prevent your application from starting. This should also be a warning and not blocking to start your application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot - An illegal reflective access operation has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956945/spring-boot-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred)