# An illegal reflective access operation has occurred Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-9

I'm using Apache POI to work with excel files, as of Java 9 I get this message, according to this post [JDK9: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred. org.python.core.PySystemState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys) we should wait for the developer to fix the issue, but should I leave it like that in my new production version? I think it shouldn't be a problem if I skip the warning.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper (file:/T:/Workspace/Java/Sections%20Manager/libs/poi/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager.setEntityExpansionLimit(int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Just a go through about Java 9 support and also if you can use nightly builds - http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/support-for-Java-9-td5729928.html. Anyway whether or not proceeding with those warning is your decision and rest of us can just add our opinions based on how long and what purpose do you want to use such code in production.

Comment: If I were you then I would at least create a bug in the Apache POI issue tracker (assuming there isn't a bug already).

Comment: See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62151 and https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61572. For Java 10 support there is additionally https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62187

Answer (score 6):

Add the updated "poi-ooxml" dependency. It will resolve all the above warnings.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Even newer is `4.1.2` which solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error I encountered was :
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper (file:/D:/Libary/poi-3.12/poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SecurityManager.setEntityExpansionLimit(int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

please use poi-3.6 or a later version,I use poi-3

Comment: There's no need to repeat error message - it's the same as OP's (only file path is different)

Comment: I'm using poi 3.8, but I'm still experiencing this error