# Illegal reflective access when I stop SpringBoot web application with Tomcat 9 and Java10

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-10, java-module, tomcat9

I'm trying Java 10 development with Spring Boot 2 and I encounter some issues.

The application is a simple webapp based upon Spring Boot 2. The application launch is ok but when I stop it, I get this warning:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/CS/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.11/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.11.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

As you see, I already switch the embedded Tomcat server from version 8 to 9.0.11 to be compliant with the Java module system.

And the application is launched with the option:
`--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`

Does anybody know why I get this message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDK9: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred. org.python.core.PySystemState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys)

Comment: I get exactly the same error when I try to rebuild project to update classpath while running springboot devtools livereload. @nullpointer, no. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @OnomeSotu can you explain, how this is not a duplicate of the other question linked?

Comment: Use also `--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To silence these warnings, you will need the following options in your startup script:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
```

as you can see in the [Tomcat 9 startup script](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/bin/catalina.sh#L306-L308).

The fixes for the warnings are [not likely to be addressed anytime soon](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201809.mbox/%3C6416c4e0-4c85-d76b-a201-6643a0a6421c@apache.org%3E):

> > Are there plans to address these in a future release?
>
> Not at the moment.
>
> We'll keep the explicit clearing in place as long as we can. Once it
>   is permanently blocked we'll probably have to rely on the fact that
>   the Maps in question use a WeakReference and wait for GC to clear the
>   references. That will make tracking down genuine memory leaks harder
>   so we'll have to see if we can persuade the JRE team to provide some
>   sort of replacement API if/when we reach that point.