# Warning Illegal reflective access while calling servlet class

Tags: java, eclipse

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/lib/catalina.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

JAVA version 4.18
Eclipse 2021-03
I am always getting this error when I try to call servlet class using the tomcat8.5 server in my Jsp project in eclipse.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52185626/illegal-reflective-access-when-i-stop-springboot-web-application-with-tomcat-9-a?

Comment: Because time is so long
Want to ask again

Comment: JAVA version 4.18 Eclipse 2021-03 - What kind of a java version is it? Java versions should be 1.5 - 1.8 or 9 - 16. Could you edit the question to add correct version ?