# Spark installation issue , java Exception

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, installation

When i try to run either pyspark, spark-shell, any other spark command right after installation it throws this exception.

Please suggest a way-out its been pending since long, i have also tried installing spark through Brew, but no success.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/opt/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.3-hadoop2.6.0.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2214)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2214)
        at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.<init>(SparkIMain.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter.<init>(SparkILoop.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createInterpreter(SparkILoop.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:949)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
        at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:49)
        ... 35 more
    Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
    To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")## Heading ##
```

Comment: What is the environment? I think it has to do something with the permissions.

Comment: Are you using Java 9 or later?

Comment: If you are using Java 9 look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install Java8 version, preferably the 8u-151 version. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html.

Also you will have to set up HOME and PATH

```
New windows environments:
1. HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark\hadoop
2. JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
3. SCALA_HOME = C:\spark\scala
4. SPARK_HOME = C:\spark\spark
PYSPARK_PYTHON = C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\python.exe
5. PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Scripts\jupyter.exe
6. PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = notebook
```