# What does "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" with Kotlin, using IntelliJ IDEA, mean?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

Simply doing the JetBrains introduction, Hello World.

What does all this mean? Installation problem? So many different versions of things I've had to download.

```
-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=52283:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Users\Student-CHCS201\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-compiler.jar;C:\Users\Student-CHCS201\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar;C:\Users\Student-CHCS201\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:\Users\Student-CHCS201\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-script-runtime.jar org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -kotlin-home C:\Users\Student-CHCS201\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc -script C:/Users/Student-CHCS201/IdeaProjects/FirstExample/src/Main.kts
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/Student-CHCS201/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Spending 2 days trying to just start the thing so far lol

Comment: "spending 2 days trying to just start the thing so far" – That's just a warning and should not prevent your application from running. It has to do with the _Java Platform Module System_ introduced in Java 9. Here are some related Q&As: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys/46230678

Comment: so it should still run my code? but it didnt, what did i do wrong?

Comment: `what did i do wrong?` You need to at least show us what code you are trying to run and what is the expected and actual result you are getting. Because the posted output has no relation to the problem of `so it should still run my code? but it didnt`

Comment: I'm not sure what you might have done wrong. Can you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem? And possibly a link to the tutorial you're using?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. I tried different versions (1.4.32, 1.4. 31, 1.4.20) of `kotlin compiler`, they all had the same problem on `windows`. On `Ubuntu` they work perfectly. Anyway, I install version 1.4.10 on windows, and the problem got solved.